# Geometric approach to factoring numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm working on the following idea:

Suppose you have have the circle $C=\left\{ {x, y} \in \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2=65\right\}$  and we start with an integer point (i.e., with integer coordinates), say $(1,8)$. Now, we pass a line with rational slope through the point and intersect it again with the circle. The obtained point, $P$, obviously has rational coordinates. Then, we choose the closest integer point to $P$, let's name it $Q$, and we trace the line $PQ$. Now is when it gets interesting. Intersecting $PQ$ with $C$ we obtained a new rational point, and there's a theorem that claims that the common denominator in the rational coordinates of this new point is less or equal than a half of the common denominator in the coordinates of $P$ (to see a proof of this, consult André Weil's Number Theory - An approach through history, chapter 3, appendix II). So, if we iterate this process a sufficient number of times, we get a new integer point in $C$ (could be the original point $(1,8)$ or a new one).

The main application of this process is the factoring of numbers, because if we have a number that is the sum of two squares in two different ways (not counting with signal changes), then this number is composite, so if we run this process and get a different integer point in the end, then we found out that the number is not prime. For example, this would perfectly apply to the factorization of Fermat Numbers $F_{n}$, with $C=\left\{ {x, y} \in \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2=F_{n}+1\right\}$ and the starting point $(F_{n},1)$.

One thing that might be interesting is to notice that, as this is a finite process, there is a small circle arc of rational points around a fixed rational point such that the output (the final point) is the same for all of them, so this method induces a division in the circle made by the different output integer points on it.

I'm putting this problem here because i think that it's an interesting idea that maybe be developed. By now, i'm just trying to find out any patterns that arise from this method, but i didn't get much farther, because the complexity of the process rapidly increases with the increase in the radius of the circle (as the "distribution" of the closest integer points to a given rational point becomes messy). I would be very interested to discuss this problem and to receive any ideas or properties that might be interesting to study, so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Such methods already exist using elliptic curves, though it is not quite the same idea. The idea of using rational points to construct more rational points is what we do. However, the main issue is that it is not known given an typical equation if rational solutions, nevertheless integer solutions, exist. However, should they exist there are many theorems which let us do interesting work with them. But without such points, the work would be futile. You are guaranteed 4 rational points if your circle has rational radius. However, these 4 points would not be 'useful' for your method.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick statistical analysis. Starting with points uniformly distributed on the first quadrant of the circle x^2 + y^2=2^32+1, the final point is almost always (1, 2^16) and [20449,62264) shows up less than 4% of the times (here I have made x and y positive and exchanged x and y so 0 < x < y). For x^2+y^2=2^64+1, the chance of getting (1438793759,4046803256) is less than 0.1% (I don't have sufficient statistical data).

Although there are two solutions with 0 < x < y and x^2+y^2=2^64+1, the obvious solution x=1,y=2^32 seems to be the final point for almost all initial values. This is disheartening!

On a side note: Is it possible to directly contact the original poster?